# Removing Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, self-join

I have the below query

```
SELECT h.*
FROM   table1 h
       LEFT JOIN table1 e
              ON e.fundno = h.fundno 
                 AND e.trantype = 'D'
                 AND e.modifiedon > h.modifiedon
WHERE  e.fundno IS NULL
       AND h.trantype != 'D'
```

Is there way to avoid the self join. I know it can be rewritten using `Not Exists` but I am trying to avoid hitting the table twice..

If the `trantype` is same then we can use `Row_Number` to do this.. since `trantype` is different I couldn't find a way to do it..

Comment: It would actually help if you described what the query should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want non-D rows where there is no "D" row modifed at a laster time.  You could use window functions:

```
select h.*
from (select h.*,
             max(case when h.transtype = 'D' then modifiedon end) over (partition by fundno) as last_d_modifiedon
      from table1 h
     ) h
where (last_d_modifiedon is null or last_d_modifiedon < modifiedon) and
      h.transtype <> 'D';
```